# Handle SelectedItemChanged in a treeview with multiple object types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I'm trying to work with the WPF treeview but having some problems to get the SelectedItemChanged as I want. My setup is currently like this:

A class:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class TestCase
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public ObservableCollection<string> DataSets { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create an observable collection in my view model with a couple of test cases and bind them to xaml like this:

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="TestCases"
    ItemsSource="{Binding TestCases}"
    Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedTestCaseChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestCases, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testCases:TestCase}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSets}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

This give me a nice treeview that look like this:

```
Name 
  - DataSet
  - DataSet 
Name2 
  - DataSet
  - etc
```

But the problem is this part:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedTestCaseChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestCases, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This works fine if the user select "Name", but will of course fail if they click on a DataSet as it can't convert a string to TestCase.

So I would like to do a couple of things here:

- Make it so you can't select Name (just expand it), is that possible?
- When you select a DataSet I would like to get the "parent" TestCase togheter with the name of the selected DataSet. Is it possible to manipulate the command parameters in some way to get this?

I guess it should be pretty easy to do it from code behind by doing some manual checking but what about mvvm like this?

**Update 1** My command method in my view model:

```
    [OnCommand("SelectedTestCaseChangedCommand")]
    public void SelectedTestCaseChanged(TestCase testCase)
    {
        currentTestCase = testCase;
        MessengerInstance.Send(new SelectedTestCaseChangedMessage(testCase));
    }
```

Comment: what means it will fail? exception?

Comment: Yeah, InvalidCastException as my command method takes a TestCase right now. My goal would be to have a command method that takes a TestCase + String (the dataset name), if it's possible. Have a command method with just a simple string won't work as different test cases can have  datasets with the same name (so I won't be able to know which test case it is)

Comment: can you show the command method you have? and do you need both at the same time like `myMethod(string a, TestCase b)` or is it okay when you just get one of then, but it can be `string` or a `TestCase`

Comment: Sure, have added my command method (using Fody, but could be a relaycommand or anything). I would need both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Command is implemented with `RelayCommand` as you mentioned then the command looks e.g. like this:

```
private ICommand _selectedTestCaseChangedCommand;

public ICommand SelectedTestCaseChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_selectedTestCaseChangedCommand == null)
        {
            _selectedTestCaseChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(SelectedTestCaseChanged);
        }

        return _selectedTestCaseChangedCommand;
    }
}
```

You you define the `SelectedTestCaseChanged` Method as you did, but i would recommend to use the Parameter Type as `object` because object can be everything. Then you just have to check what your parameter/selected item is. You have two possibilities to do this. The `is` operator or the `as` cast with a null check following it.

```
private void SelectedTestCaseChanged(object obj)
{
    if (obj is TestCase)
    {
        var testCase = (TestCase)obj;
        // Work with testCase
    }

    if (obj is string)
    {
        // Do nothing or whatever
    }

    // Another option is
    var testCase = obj as TestCase;
    if (testCase != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

If you want to get the parent of a `TreeViewItem` you need to go up the `Visual Tree` of WPF, because `TreeViewItems` have no Parent element.

The method is decriped [in this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005119/get-the-parent-node-of-a-child-in-wpf-c-sharp-treeview).

You may get the parent of the selected and fire the command with the parent element. i would do this in code behind, but i have no experience there.

---

I would not disable the selection of the name, because with the solution above you are able to handle the case you don't want. moreover the user feels like the disabled Names are a bug..

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it's a good way to check for both objects. But it won't really help me when it's required for me to get both the object and it's parent. If there is no other answer I guess I have to go with code behind.

Comment: code behind is no problem in `MVVM`, but you should not mix up e.g. the `View` and the `ViewModel`